# Google V8 - Neither v8.dll nor v8.dll.lib getting built in release mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, v8

I've followed the [Building with GN](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20GN) instructions to build Google V8 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015. What I did:

Getting V8, after downloading and unpacking the [depot-tools](https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra/depot_tools.zip).

```
C:\build-depot> set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
C:\build-depot> gclient
C:\build-depot> set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
C:\build-depot> fetch v8
```

Generating build files...

```
C:\build-depot\v8> python tools\dev\v8gen.py x64.debug
C:\build-depot\v8> python tools\dev\v8gen.py x64.release
```

... and compiling

```
C:\build-depot\v8> ninja -C out.gn\x64.debug
C:\build-depot\v8> ninja -C out.gn\x64.release
```

Static libraries generated in **debug** mode:

```
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug>dir /s/b *.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\cctest.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\icui18n.dll.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\icuuc.dll.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\mkpeephole.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\mksnapshot.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\v8.dll.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\v8_libbase.dll.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\v8_libplatform.dll.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\obj\build\config\sanitizers\options_sources.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\obj\testing\gmock\gmock.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\obj\testing\gmock\gmock_main.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.debug\obj\testing\gtest\gtest.lib
```

Static libraries generated in **release** mode:

```
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\v8_libbase.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\v8_libplatform.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\build\config\sanitizers\options_sources.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\testing\gmock\gmock.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\testing\gmock\gmock_main.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\testing\gtest\gtest.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\third_party\icu\icui18n.lib
C:\depot_tools\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj\third_party\icu\icuuc.lib
```

**Problem**

As you can see in the list above, `v8.dll.lib` is generated in debug mode, but is missing in release mode, which BTW is also true for `v8.dll`. Two questions:

1. Why aren't these libraries generated in release mode?
2. How should I link against V8 in release mode, when these libs are missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Release mode builds are statically linked by default, as opposed to creating a `v8.dll` shared library. You can change that by running `gn args out.gn\x64.release` and adding the line `is_component_build = true`, then save and close the file, and rebuild.