# linking v8 to c++ application

Tags: c++, v8, visual-studio-2019

I'm having trouble trying to get v8 working with visual studio 2019.
I have followed the compiling guide on v8.dev and built it on windows.
I have followed [this][Google V8 - Neither v8.dll nor v8.dll.lib getting built in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199892/google-v8-neither-v8-dll-nor-v8-dll-lib-getting-built-in-release-mode) answer to obtain .dll and .lib files.
Now I'm stuck. I tried to build the examples they show on the official site (https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/6.8/samples/hello-world.cc) but I get all sorts of errors.
From what I understand, I need .dll, .lib and .h files. I have them, but I'm not able to use them correctly in visual studio.
I have tried adding the header files under include directories and .lib files under Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies without luck.
There are good chances anyone who has worked with c++ beyond simple console programs will laugh at my ignorance, and I would understand that.
Any help would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE**
These are the steps i followed to use v8:
1) Created a new c++ console solution
2) Added header directory at Configuration > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories
3) Added dll and v8.dll.lib folder in Configuration > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies
4) Pasted this (https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/6.8/samples/hello-world.cc) code to my editor

The first type of error I got is E1696: it looks like some headers contain references to other headers with absolute paths and not relative paths.
I fix this by myself making reference paths relative in headers.

Then I get 23 LNK2019 errors:
[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgOnW.png)

What should I do?

Comment: Hi, could you please post exact errors you get and any additional info that could help in helping you. :)

Comment: I updated the question with more data

Comment: You probably need to link to these v8.dll.lib;v8_libbase.dll.lib;v8_libplatform.dll.lib, that is add them to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies

Comment: I have done that, but it doesn't help. Also, I would like to link dynamically, not statically, so I can just swap dll when they update v8